# Change color of cell in excel if all values of a list are present in different column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to change color of cell in excel if all values of a list are present in a different column.

[image: This is my custom list with some values]

I, also have another column with some values.

I want that color of *myColumn* cell should be *red* if all values of *MyList* are not present.

[image]

And it should be *green* if all values from *MyList* are present in *myColumn*

[image]

I tried doing it using `conditional formatting`, but it changes color of cell based on single cell value.

```
=INDEX(B2:H2,MATCH(D2,B13:B15,0))
```

How can I do it based on values of a list?

Comment: can you please add another picture to show the expected format on your `myColumn` and explain why it is the case? Also please specify how did you set up the `conditional formatting` and maybe post the formula.

Comment: @TerryW Added pictures as per your suggestion. I expect this because I want to check if I have covered all possible cases in my test which will be defined in `myColumn`. And all possible cases are predefined in `MyList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **MyList** being Cell `B2:H2` in my example;
- **myColumn** being Cell `B5:B7` in my example. Please note I have named this range in the form of a **Table** so when I add values to this column, new values are automatically added to the named range. **Set the background color of the header `myColumn` to red**.

[image: named ranges]

Then you can set the following formula as the conditional formatting rule for Cell `B4` which is the header `myColumn`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(MyList,myColumn,0))*1)=COLUMNS(MyList)
```

> **MATCH** will compare the values in `MyList` with `myColumn` and return a number for a match and `#N/A` for no match, **ISNUMBER** will convert the results to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. **SUMPRODUCT** will sum the results and if all values are matched it should return `7` in the above example. Then compare the summed result with the expected result `COLUMNS(MyList)` which is `7` as well. If match, the formula will return `TRUE`, which will then trigger the conditional format to **turn the cell background colour to green**.

[image: Formatting Rule]

If I add more values to `myColumn` to match `MyList`:

[image: Result]

> Please note the formula only checks if all `MyList` values are present in `myColumn` but not the other way around, which means if your `myColumn` also contains other number such as `8`, `9`, `10` which are not in `MyList`, the header will still turn green as long as it contains all values from `MyList` regardless if it has extra values or not.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Check out the image:
`myrow` has values that are `VLOOKUP()` against `mycolumn` and if `isnumber()` will return TRUE, otherwise FALSE. Then do an `and()` on all the resulting values and that result can be used to determine the color of the cell.

So **by setting the cell's default fill color to RED**, it will by default be RED, unless the following formatting rule is met, then it will be GREEN:

[image: Image2]

Comment: I am getting FALSE every time, even though same values are present in both row and column

Comment: A couple things: double-triple-check that your ranges in your `VLOOKUP()` are correct, and also make sure both your row and column data are numbers (as in, 5 is different than string "5", which is also different than a cell containing ' 5' because it includes an extra space). If that all looks correct, update your question to include some more screenshots and your equations and I'll take another look at that